# Secondary bacta production centers

Tags: star-wars, medicine

Star Wars' miracle healing potion, bacta, was primarly produced at Thyferra. There are however other planets in which bacta was made, in far smaller volume, or maybe even for a limited period of time. Do we know what those planets are?

Comment: They can make it artificially in the New Republic Era; https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bacta#cite_note-Last_Jedi_Junior-21

Answer (score 1):

Hetzal Prime was one.  At the time of the 'Great Hyperspace Disaster' Hetzal was growing a small amount of bacta and had plans to scale up bacta production.  The Hetzal System system included Hetzal Prime, a planet with two moons, Fruited and Rooted, and three suns, the largest being an R-class star. The planet and both moons were totally committed to agriculture and because of its unique system it was said that every plant in the galaxy could be grown there.

The High Republic Era novel *[Light of the Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_High_Republic:_Light_of_the_Jedi)* talks about the effort to grow bacta on Hetzal Prime.

> There was that bacta stuff he had been reading about too.  Some kind of miracle replacement for juvan they were trying to grow on the prime world. It was supposed to revolutionize medicine if they could ever figure out how to farm it in volume.

and

> Elzar Mann standing alone on a rocky promontory overlooking a farm where the new miracle drug bacta was produced in extremely limited quantities...

The Great Hyperspace Disaster and the ensuing "Emergences" put a hamper on those plans.